# Shortest way to verify integer values

Tags: c#, validation, if-statement

i am reading values from the file and checking the values my code is

```
while (sr.EndOfStream != null)
{
     a= sr.EndOfStream ? "" : sr.ReadLine();
     if (Convert.ToInt32(a) < 1)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(a+ " is not a right value");
         flag = true;
         break;
     }
     b= sr.EndOfStream ? "" : sr.ReadLine();
     if (Convert.ToInt32(b) < 1)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(b+ " is not a right value");
         flag = true;
         break;
     }
     ....
```

Is there any other way to make my code look good

Comment: Try to align it to the left?

Comment: File.readalllines and then try parse each in a for loop, store the false integers in a list

Comment: This belongs over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The C# language provides some utility methods for this purpose. We describe an easy way to convert strings to ints. This approach avoids exceptions when a string cannot be converted.

```
        int value;

        if (Int32.TryParse("String Value", out value))
        {
            //Converted
        }
        else
        {
            //Can not parse to Int 
        }
```

Comment: Best is your opinion.

Comment: Note that 123.0 will be considered non-integer according to this code.

Comment: An integer is a number that has no fractional part, and no digits after the decimal point. An integer can be positive, negative or zero.
So 123.0 is not integer value

Answer (score 2):

I would use the very nice `TryParse` method to validate your input, and process one line each time through the `while` loop.

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    int a;
    string s = sr.EndOfStream ? "" : sr.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(s, out a))
    {
        // Use the value of a, since it is an integer
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a + " is not a right value");
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing from my phone so excuse the formatting...

```
var lines = file.readalllines(path);
var indexes //list
for(int I = 0; I < lines.count; I++)
{
    int current;
    if(!int.TryParse(lines[I], out current)
        indexes.add(I);
}
```

Indexes will now be a list of every line that is erroneous (0 indexed)